# How to get id of selected option in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a very simple select box.

```
<FormGroup>
  <label for='category' className='label'>Category</label>
  <select ref="categoryName">
    {categoriesList}
  </select>
</FormGroup>
```

and

```
let categoriesList = categories.map(category =>
  <option id={category.id}>
      {category.type}
   </option>
 )
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the value of 'id' attribute of the option that's selected in the dropdown, I want to use this value for some further processing. please advise. thanks

Comment: Generally speaking you don't,  make id part of your state.  And then your render function can update based on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `onChange` event handler to the select which checks for the selected index and retrieve the id from the selected option.

```
onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const index = e.target.selectedIndex;
  const el = e.target.childNodes[index]
  const option =  el.getAttribute('id');  
}

<FormGroup>
  <label for='category' className='label'>Category</label>
  <select onChange={onChangeHandler}>
      {categories.map(category =>
          <option id={category.id}>
             {category.type}
          </option>
      )}
  </select>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: This is a bit of an anti-pattern for React.

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should try and avoid getting state from the DOM.

React works really well if you control state, and leave React to render your state.

Below is a simple example, basically all I do is store the state index into an array,.  And when I update this, the React view will update accordingly. How you store state is then totally up to you, and not the DOM.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const lookup = [
  {id: 1, value: 'one'},
  {id: 2, value: 'two'},
  {id: 3, value: 'three'}
];


function List() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1); 
  const value = selected !== -1 && lookup[selected];
  return <div>
    <select 
      onChange={(e) => setSelected(e.target.value)}
      value={selected}>
      <option>Please Selected an option</option>
      {lookup.map((m, ix) => {
        return <option 
          key={m.id}
          value={ix}
        >
         {m.value}
        </option>
      })};
    </select>
    {value &&
    <div style={{marginTop: "2rem"}}>
      You selected ID <span>{value.id}</span>
      value
      <span>{value.value}</span>
    </div>}
   </div>;
}



ReactDOM.render(<List/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```css
body, select, option {
 font-size: 20px;
}
select, option {
 padding: 0.5rem;
}
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write a sample code you can use or look at to implement, just pass the id as a value and set the state

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 0, minWidth: 300 }} style={{"width": "100%", "marginTop":"20px",}}>
                          <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Select System Type</InputLabel>
                          <Select
                            labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
                            id="demo-multiple-chip"
                            multiple
                            value={systemTypeMultiple}
                            onChange={handleMultSelectDropDownSystemTypeChange}
                            input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Select System Type" />}
                            renderValue={(selected) => (
                              <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
                                {selected.map((value) => (
                                  <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                                ))}
                              </Box>
                            )}
                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                          >
                            {systemData ? systemData.map((system_types, index) => (
                              <MenuItem
                                key={system_types.system_type_id}
                                value={`${system_types.system_type_id} ${selectedSystemTypesId.push(system_types.name)}`}
                                // value={index}
                                style={getStyles(system_types.name, systemTypeMultiple, theme)}
                              >
                                {system_types.name}
                              </MenuItem>
                            )) : null}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
```