# getting the ID when user is selected in dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, react-redux

I have a dropdown list in react. in which `username` is getting displayed. my requirement is to get `id` instead of `username` when user select any value.

[image]

I have below code for that.

```
                            <select
                                onChange={(e) => selectedUser(e)}
                                className=" form-select-control">
                                <option value="">Please select the user</option>
                                {active &&
                                    users.map((user: any) => (
                                        <option>{user.displayName}</option>
                                    ))}
                            </select>



  const selectedUser = (e: any) => {
        setUser(e.target.value);
    };
```

on dropdown I am getting data from API. below is the data.

[image]

I am getting `ID` along with `displayName`(username) from API. my question is under `selectedUser` method how can I get ID for selected user. is there any other way as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

You need to define a `key` if you create DOM elements with React when you iterate through an array with `.map()` anyway (else you'll get a warning in the console of your browser). You can use the `key` to get the `user.id`:

```
<select onChange={(e) => selectedUser(e)} className=" form-select-control">
    <option value="">Please select the user</option>
    {active &&
        users.map((user: any) => (
            <option key={user.id}>{user.displayName}</option>
        ))}
</select>;

const selectedUser = (e: any) => {
    setUser(e.target.key);
};
```

You could also save the `user.id` in `id={user.id}` and grab it via `e.target.id`.

Comment: value is coming as null

Comment: Hi,can you explain this line ?  "You could also save the user.id in id={user.id} and grab it via e.target.id.

"

Comment: I see the problem now. The option is not the `e.target`. The `e.target` is the `select` element. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264788/how-to-get-id-of-selected-option-in-react-js). This will solve the issue.

Comment: Niraj did what I mean by "You could also save the `user.id` in `id={user.id}` and grab it via e.target.id".

Comment: thank you. please update the answer if possible for other people. I am accepting this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code something like this

```
                        <select
                            onChange={(e) => selectedUser(e)}
                            className=" form-select-control">
                            <option value="">Please select the user</option>
                            {active &&
                                users.map((user: any) => (
                                    <option id={user.id}>{user.displayName}</option>
                                ))}
                        </select>



  const selectedUser = (e: any) => {
    setUser(e.target.id);
};
```

Comment: Value is coming as null